# In Python 2.7,why sometimes it can't print after using zlib.decompress()

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

the code is:

```
import zlib;
s="witch which has which witches wrist watch";
z=zlib.compress(s);
print(len(s));
print(len(z));
print(s);
print(z,"\n");
a=zlib.decompress(z);
print(a);#here,in console sometimes will stop at here 
print(zlib.crc32(s));
```

why?something wrong about buffer?

Comment: Works on my machine. By the way, if you're using 2.7, you shouldn't put your print statements in parentheses. If you do, you'll get weird results when you try to print more than one thing, ex. `print(z,"\n")` will get printed as a tuple.

Comment: I think you have something seriously wrong with your python installation if the `print(a)` statement is getting hung up. Of course, it could be the line before `a=zlib.decompress(z);` is where the hang up is happening in which case your zlib installation may be messed up. Either way, I might try to reinstall python and retry your test.

Comment: Also, what's up with all the closing semicolons?

Comment: The `print z` prints compressed bytes, which is random garbage for the terminal.  It might lock it up or have other side effects.  You should try to `print repr(z)` instead.